# How can I pull a file in /data/data/ from a rooted android device in one click using a windows' .bat file?

Tags: android, batch-file, adb, pull

I wrote the following .bat file, but it did not work for me. Could anybody help me?

```
adb shell
su
cd /data/data
cp -r com.example.myapp /sdcard
exit
adb pull /sdcard/com.example.myapp
```

The .bat stop in the first command and did not go ahead. Just as this
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4rni.png) show. I would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `adb` as root

```
adb root
```

then you can just do

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.myapp/ .
```

Comment: I am sorry your suggestion is not appropriate for me. I want to copy a whole directory, but the destination directory contains nothing after executing this two commands. Additionally, when I copy a single file in that directory, it show me a "Permission denied" message.