# Test instrumentation process crashed - where is the .txt file?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Sometimes, while Espresso testing, I see the following exception.

```
Test instrumentation process crashed.  Check package_name.TestName#methodName.txt for details
```

Where is this `.txt` file stored? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

#### Use Case

In Jenkins (CI), I want the logs to see exactly what stacktrace caused the crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the Android Orchestrator log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435789/how-to-see-the-android-orchestrator-log)

Answer (score 28):

If you are working with an emulator, in A.S open Device File Explorer and go to:
***/data/user_de/0/android.support.test.orchestrator/files/***, then you can look for a particular file there

**EDIT: June 25 - 2019** >> If you have updated to AndroidX dependencies, then the .txt file is located in
**/data/user_de/0/androidx.test.orchestrator/files/**

Comment: please note that this would require you to root your phone

Comment: You can use `run-as` command to access files without root. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435789/how-to-see-the-android-orchestrator-log

Comment: Thanks for sharing this I would never have found it myself

Answer (score 9):

In my case, it was simpler to just check Logcat, rather than listen to that recommendation

Answer (score 4):

For others encountering this issue, as @antek pointed out the files might not be accessible on a non-rooted device.  You might try using an emulator running a non-Google Play API where you can obtain a root shell.

```
adb root
adb shell
ls /data/data/androidx.test.orchestrator/files
```

Alternatively, you could try running the tests using the debugger.

Comment: Note: `/data/data/android.support.test.orchestrator/files` before Android X

Answer (score 4):

I could not find the text file, but I was able to get logcat and view the fatal that caused the orchestrator to crash

first I clear the logcat

> adb logcat -c

then I run the test, then I grab the logcat

> adb logcat > ~/Desktop/logcat

then I open logcat file and search for string `FATAL`

Answer (score -1):

1. I just did wipe data in Android studio for my emulator using Device manager.
2. Restarted the emulator and run the test works for me